# Where is the 'unread notifications queue'?

Tags: 8.0, notifications, 7.x

This happened - I was in living room and I heard sound of my phone from some other room. I was watching TV so I checked the phone after a while. But there was nothing on the lock screen of the phone after I reached it.

Next day I get to the office and my colleague asked: Why didn't you answered me yesterday, I texted you on Whatsapp...

This way I located the source of the mysterious phone-ring. But I wouldn't know if my colleague didn't tell me...

What is the way to find any unread notifications? Or how to find whether there even are any on the phone? I don't have to hear it every time...

Comment: +1 - I was woken up by a toast message at 4am this morning but I have no idea which app it was!

Comment: related: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3443/how-can-i-find-out-what-a-sound-means-on-my-phone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit**: As of the 8.1 update this is no longer valid. I am leaving the old answer below for historic reference.

---

As of the 8.1 update an Action Center has been added. You can access it by swiping down from the top of the screen. Similar to the IOS, you will have notifications there as well as shortcuts for bluetooth, wifi, airplane mode, etc...

---

*Old answer*

For general Toast Notifications, There is no queue. Applications, however, keep track of them. The list below assumes you have the corresponding app pinned to your home screen

- The SMS app will have a number on the tile indicating how many txt you have. You can also see this from your lock screen.
- Email doesn't give you a toast notification, but you can see how many you have on the live tile. This number **isn't** how many unread messages you have, but how many you have gotten since you last opened it. This is also on your lock screen.
- Rowi (Twiter client) has an option for toast notificaiton for direct messages, and mentioned. It shows how many of these you have on the tile as well. There are other applications that do this as well.

In short, there is no "unread notification queue" to check, but each app has its own experience. Try pinning the application to your home screen for quick visual feedback.

Comment: Ok, I take 'pin the app to your home screen' as the solution for my problem. Like this, I can create own queue of notification-aware apps on my home screen. Now - how do I found which apps support notifications? :)

Comment: It is hard to say. Some say in the description. For others, just catch them as you go. When you see the app send a notification, pin it and see if the developer added live tile support as well. For some apps you may just be out of luck :(