# Why doesn't Hotmail show a lockscreen notification envelope?

Tags: notifications, outlook

My three Gmail accounts play the notification sound, show an envelope on the lockscreen and display a 'new unread' count on the live tile, but my Hotmail account only plays the sound and shows the count on the live tile. So I always have to unlock the phone to figure out where that sound was coming from. I know there are some [limitations](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/462/where-is-the-unread-notifications-queue), but I would expect Hotmail to show the envelope.

Why doesn't my Hotmail account show a lockscreen notification envelope?

Comment: Is this for the "main" live account associated to the phone?

Comment: This is for an additional Hotmail account and is not the main live account.

Comment: I use the main Live ID as e-mail account and the envelope is shown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are only 5 slots on the lock screen available for notifications, and of those only 3 are for email. 1 of those is dedicated for your Live account.

The way it is determined is by the order you added them. You will need to remove/re-add the accounts in a different order if you want to have the Hotmail account there (you will lose a different one, of course) or link email accounts.

I have 4 accounts (Live, Gmail, Hotmail, Google apps) but linked the Gmail/Hotmail accounts so I get notifications for all accounts. The downside is the linked account **doesn't show which account** has the email. You just get a notifications saying there is one. It is better than nothing though.

[Original Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wppeople/lock-screen-notifications-with-multiple-exchange/bcdb6125-0141-4da3-87de-98e9e91dbe4f). Highlight posted below.

> ...There are only 5 "slots" on the lock screen for notifications and  they are,
>   moving left to right:
>
> 1. Missed calls/voice mail.
> 2. Text messaging.
> 3. Primary Windows Live ID email.
> 4. Email account #2.
> 5. Email account #3.

Comment: WTF Amazing answer. I did't know you can have 3 email notification.

Comment: Great answer for a completely mental implementation. It is a shame that I am wasting slot #3. Hopefully WP8 will completely overhaul notifications.