# How can I not synch email from my primary (Live) account?

Tags: sync, email, microsoft-account, notifications, lock-screen

I've got a 4(!) different email accounts synching with my phone, and I'd like to specify which ones appear as icons on my lock screen.

Currently my lock screen only displays the following three, in this order from right to left:

1. Personal email (random IMAP server)
2. Gmail
3. Hotmail (Primary account)

However, I'd like to remove the Hotmail icon (I never use the mail features) and have my work account appearing on there instead (it's an Outlook/Exchange account if that matters).

I thought it might be controlled by the order the accounts were listed on my home screen, but reordering them on there doesn't seem to have any affect on the lock screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for why the order you added them isn't working, see [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/520/131).

> There are only 5 slots on the lock screen available for notifications,
>   and of those only 3 are for email. **1 of those is dedicated for your
>   Live account**.

To get rid of it you need to tell your phone to not sync email with that account.

Go to `Settings` -> `Email+Accounts` -> `Select Account`. Under "Content to sync" uncheck "email". It should solve your problem.

Comment: Cheers for your help :)