# how to sync gmail well with WP8?

Tags: sync, gmail

So I got a new Lumia 920 but I can get gmail to work properly. I set it up using the "gmail" option when you create an account. I set to download items **as they arrive**.

But when I get an email from gmail, the phone doesn't seem to realize, I can only see the email if I open the gmail account. However, my iPhone does receive the email from gmail instantly.

Another thing that happens is that when I read an email in the gmail account in the phone, it won't show as "read" in my laptop's gmail page in the browser. Not even if I refresh the inbox.

In my iPhone it all works perfectly, I get the notifications instantly and it's all perfectly synchronized.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Go into your settings and open Email and Accounts section again. If there is a problem with the syncing, you will see a status underneath the account name. Is there a notification there?

Comment: no there isn't, it looks like it's set up properly, it just that emails don't get to the phone if I don't manually sync

Comment: For notification problem, how many other email accounts do you have setup? Could it be related to this http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/519/why-doesnt-hotmail-show-a-lockscreen-notification-envelope ?

Comment: I retuned my lumia (not for this reason) and got a galaxy note 2. Best decision ever! It's an amazing phone :)

Answer (score 2):

This might the solution you are looking for:
http://www.neowin.net/news/how-to-use-google-services-in-windows-phone-8

Check the section **Push Gmail and syncing contacts**:

> While there is an easy option to simply sync your account as a Google
>   account in the settings, you'll get better results if you set it up as
>   an Exchange ActiveSync account because it enables push email. Don't
>   worry, because all of your contacts and your primary calendar will be
>   synced across as well, just like if you were to set it up as a
>   standard Google account.
>
> . . .
>
> To set up said Exchange ActiveSync account, go to the phone settings
>   and then to email+accounts > add an account > Advanced Setup. In this
>   menu, enter your Google account's email address and password, click
>   next and then choose Exchange ActiveSync. From this menu with more
>   options, the necessary Server box appears; here enter m.google.com,
>   click sign in and you're all good to go (leave the Domain box blank).

Screenshots and more details at the linked article.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.