# How can I find out what a sound means on my phone?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, notifications, ringtone

I have a Lumia 920 that I have been using as a wifi only device since I got it, pretty much the month it was released. Recently I put a SIM card in it and as a result I have the volume up now, because I get calls on it. Tonight it started making a strange "notification" sound yet I cannot figure out what it was trying to tell me. No missed calls (and it wasn't the incoming call noise anyway), no new texts, no new emails (and I have "no sound" for when an email comes in), no new Skypes (and I know that sound and it wasn't that), no new anythings according to the live tiles I have pinned.

What can I do, either while the sound is happening or shortly afterwards, to establish what is trying to notify me of something?

Comment: I have solved this particular sound (the phone was sitting on a chipped credit card and the NFC interactor was the source of the noise) but the question remains. In general, how can I work out what app is trying to tell me something?

Answer (score 1):

For basically every sound except the NFC sound, there will be a toast notification or popup on screen. You just have to catch it in action.

The 8.1 update (coming soon) will add a notification history, making this somewhat easier.